# Restore IPython 5.1 terminal colors to 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, ipython, freebsd

Today I upgraded my IPython installation from 3.2.3 to 5.1 via the FreeBSD ports system. If it matters, I'm using Python 3.6.

The new colors used in the terminal are *ugly* in my eyes.
(I'm using the urxvt terminal in transparent mode.)

How do I restore the looks of the IPython terminal from the 3.2.3 release?

In my `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` I've tried setting `InteractiveShell.colors` to the values listed in the [documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#terminal-colors). None of them looked like they used to.

Alternatively, I've tried most of the pygments highlighting styles available via `TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style`. They don't look good on a transparent background either.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've settled on giving the terminal window a solid dark background (base03: #002b36) from the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colorscheme, in combination with the `native` highlighting theme. This is accomplished as follows.

In my window manager setup, I have a special invocation for starting IPython in a terminal:

```
urxvt +tr -bg '#002b36' -title IPython -e ipython
```

This is necessary because my standard `urxvt` windows are set as transparent via the `.Xresources` file, and I need to override those. It is also convenient.

My `ipython_config.py` looks like this:

```
c = get_config()
c.TerminalIPythonApp.display_banner = False
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.confirm_exit = False
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style = 'native'
c.InteractiveShell.editor = 'gvim'
c.InteractiveShell.deep_reload = True
```

**Note:**
If you choose a highlighting style like I did above, the `%colors` magic does not work anymore in IPython 5.1.

**Note2:**
Better support for 24-bit colors in urxvt is [coming](http://lists.schmorp.de/pipermail/rxvt-unicode/2016q2/002261.html). Once that is released, I will probably install [pygments-style-solarized](https://github.com/shkumagai/pygments-style-solarized) and use that instead, since I'm already using solarized in gvim.